# How to get the Cell (of a ListView) under the mouse pointer?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, coordinates, cell

I wrote a thread that checks constantly if the mouse is over a ListView, because I want to show a Popup containing info about the cell I point with the mouse.

So no problem to check if the mouse is over the ListView.

But how do I check if the mouse is over a certain cell since I cannot use `ListCell.localToScreen(ListCell.getBoundsInLocal());` to get the cell coordinates on screen?

I prefer not to use ListCell event such as onMouseEntered.

Comment: The way to do this is to register mouse listeners with the `ListCell`s, or observe their `hoverProperty`. Why do you prefer not to use the provided mechanism? And why can you not use `ListCell.localToScreen(ListCell.getBoundsInLocal())`?

Comment: @James_D I don't want to use listeners because they had random bugs. I am trying to work with hoverProperty, but I'd prefer to continue without using this property.

ListCell doesn't have those properties.

Comment: @James_D hoverProperty isn't good for this purpose.
I guess I'll try with listeners, I hope they won't behave randomly as they usually do

Comment: What random bugs? And what do you mean "ListCell doesn't have those properties?" It's a `Node`, and the [`hoverProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#hoverProperty) is defined for `Node`.

Comment: Bugs have reason behind them. You say it's random because you do not understand the reason. Explain the bugs you are encountering and chances are you'll be told the reason by someone who understands it.

Comment: @user2468425 If you have code where your listeners are not behaving as you expect, feel free to post a question with sample code asking what you're doing wrong. I haven't seen any bug reports for those listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Either register handlers for `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events on each `ListCell`, or observe the `ListCell`'s `hoverProperty`. Here's an example using the second method:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class PopupOnListCellHover extends Application {

    private Popup popup ;
    private Node popupContent ;
    private Label titleLabel ;
    private Label detailsLabel ;
    private FadeTransition fadeOut ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Item> listView = new ListView<>();

        popup = new Popup();
        titleLabel = new Label();
        titleLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 1.5em ; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
        detailsLabel = new Label();
        popupContent = new VBox(10, titleLabel, detailsLabel);
        popupContent.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; "+
            "-fx-background: lightskyblue; -fx-padding:12px;");
        popup.getContent().add(popupContent);

        fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), popupContent);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeOut.setOnFinished(e -> popup.hide());

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<Item> cell = new ListCell<Item>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getName());
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
                if (isNowHovered && ! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    showPopup(cell);
                } else {
                    hidePopup();
                }
            });

            return cell ;
        });

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, i))
            .forEach(listView.getItems()::add);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showPopup(ListCell<Item> cell) {
        fadeOut.stop();
        popupContent.setOpacity(1.0);
        Bounds bounds = cell.localToScreen(cell.getBoundsInLocal());
        popup.show(cell, bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMinY());
        Item item = cell.getItem() ;
        titleLabel.setText(item.getName());
        detailsLabel.setText(String.format("This is %s.%nIt has value %d.", 
            item.getName(), item.getValue()));
    }

    private void hidePopup() {
        fadeOut.playFromStart();
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final int value ;
        private final String name ;

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            this.name = name ;
            this.value = value ;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name ;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

To use handlers for `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`, replace

```
    cell.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
        if (isNowHovered && ! cell.isEmpty()) {
            showPopup(cell);
        } else {
            hidePopup();
        }
    });
```

with

```
    cell.setOnMouseEntered(e -> showPopup(cell));
    cell.setOnMouseExited(e -> hidePopup());
```